Github Action with Angular is failing due to @rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu
I'm facing the following error when the pipeline in my GitHub actions is running:

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module
@rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu. npm has a bug related to optional
dependencies (https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4828). Please try npm i again after removing both package-lock.json and node_modules
directory.

This error is shown up when I run the test or even the build:
enter image description here
enter image description here
And here is my .yml:
enter image description here
And there are my scripts:
enter image description here
am I doing something wrong?
I have tried with other node versions and caching npm.

This question is similar to: Error in React vite project due to rollup dependency (module not found). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This problem is quite common, see this thread if you want the full explanation and all possible solutions.
Adding this to the package.json and running npm i again will usually fix it in most cases:
"optionalDependencies": {
  "@rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu": "*"
}

